# Finding duplicated values in a dictionary and printing them only in case the values with the same keys are different

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am creating a triplet dictionary from a CSV file, with key - the line numbers and values a list containing three integers. I am also creating another dictionary (names) with a key the line number and values a list of two strings. I want to find all lines containing the same triplet in case that the names pair is different.

My code so far is finding all duplication in case there is the same triplet values on two lines, but in case of a duplication on 3 and more rows it won't work correctly. I want to either update or re-write the whole script so that in case of 3 or more duplication to check if all the names values are different and print only the lines having different names. For example if we have the following triplet dictionary: 
`triplet = {1: [111, 222, 333], 2: [111, 222, 333], 3: [111, 222, 333], }` and `names = {1: ['name1', 'name2'], 2: ['name1', 'name2'], 3: ['name1', 'name3']}` This will result in creation of another dictionary: `duplicated_value_keys = {(111, 222, 333): [1, 2, 3]}` and my script won't show a duplication since `names[1] == names[2]` but in principal it should print that the triplet values on line 2 and line 3 are having different names.

```
for csv_infile in os.listdir(input_dir):
        if csv_infile.lower().endswith('.csv'):
            csv_in = os.path.join(input_dir, csv_infile)
            with open(csv_in) as f_in:
                # Creating dictionaries containing as a key the line number and as a value
                triplet = {}
                names = {}
                l_num = 0
                for line in f_in:
                    l_num += 1
                    triplet[l_num] = [(line.split('\t')[1]), (line.split('\t')[2]), (line.split('\t')[3])]
                    names[l_num] = [(line.split('\t')[4].lower().strip()), (line.split('\t')[5].lower().strip())]

                # Finding the duplicated values and creating a new dictionary with values the line numbers.
                duplicated_value_keys = collections.defaultdict(list)
                for key, value in triplet.items():
                    duplicated_value_keys[tuple(value)].append(key)
                for duplicated_keys in duplicated_value_keys.values():
                    if len(duplicated_keys) >1 and names[duplicated_keys[0]] != names[duplicated_keys[1]]: 
                        print("There is a duplicated triplet on lines: {}.\n".format(', '.join(map(str, duplicated_keys))))
```

[EDIT]: The CSV input file has the following format and it is tab delimited:

```
2       8004    3014    3       test name   1       14080   1       0       3478    1572    0       0
2       8004    3014    3       test name    1       8004    1       0       3478    1572    0       0
3       8004    3014    3       test name1   1       8004    1       0       3477    1571    0       0
```

Comment: It is still unclear what is meant by different names. Different to the first entry, different to each? If different to the first entry, then only the last entry would be displayed.

Comment: @MartinEvans, first thanks for your help. By different names I mean that the script should show the lines of the duplicated columns 1, 2, 3 only if the entries in column 4 and 5 differs for the lines. For example in my CSV example there should be only reporting regarding line 2 and 3, because column 4 and 5 on line 1 and 2 are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting duplicate lines could be done using a `defaultdict(list)`. The triplet would be the key for the dictionary and each would contain a list of line numbers and names where the triplet was found. After reading all entries in, iterate through the dictionary and display only those entries which contain different names. For example:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

triplets = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')

    for line, row in enumerate(csv_input, start=1):
        triplets[tuple(row[1:4])].append((line, list(map(str.lower, row[4:6]))))

for triplet, entries in sorted(triplets.items()):
    if len(entries) > 1 and len({tuple(names) for line, names in entries}) > 1:
        print("Duplicate triplet: {} on lines:".format(triplet))
        for line, names in entries:
            print("  {}, {}, {}".format(line, *names))
        print()
```

For the `test.csv` given, this would produce:

```
Duplicate triplet: ('13115', '3209', '3') on lines:
  44, skylink, horor film
  69, skylink, private spice

Duplicate triplet: ('13139', '3219', '3') on lines:
  8, skylink, nova cinema
  13, skylink, prima zoom

Duplicate triplet: ('8004', '3014', '3') on lines:
  2, skylink, ct 2
  3, skylink, bar 2
  4, skylink, tst 22
  5, skylink, tst 22
```

Comment: but here I don't see a check if the names are unique. My script is already outputting the duplicated triplets and then I am running `if len(duplicated_keys) >1 and names[duplicated_keys[0]] != names[duplicated_keys[1]]:` but this is only checking for the first two occurrences.

Comment: What is the expected output for your example?

Comment: `Duplicate triplet: ('8004', '3014', '3') on lines: 2, 3` because lines 1 and 2 have the same `('test', 'name')` and only line 3 has different `('test', 'name1')`

Comment: my script should return the number of the lines for a triplet column 1 to 3 (counting from 0) if the combo (column 4 and 5) for the duplicated lines is not the same. If column 4 and 5 are the same for the duplicated lines it should not report the duplication.

Comment: I have uploaded a test.csv file at [gdrive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13XJDB5D5MKTXfQRhqzrK4HYvzcshvcMJ) Currently the code you have written doesn't correctly returns the result. For example this is my output when run against the test.csv file: `Duplicate triplet: ('13115', '3209', '3') on lines: 69`
`Duplicate triplet: ('13137', '3219', '3') on lines:`
`Duplicate triplet: ('13139', '3219', '3') on lines: 13`
`Duplicate triplet: ('8004', '3014', '3') on lines: 3, 4, 5` and as you can see from the file: It should report first duplication between line 44 and 69...

Comment: ...then the second triplet is duplicate on line 10 and 11 but the entries in the 4th and 5th column are identical so it should not be printed, the third line should show line 8 and 13 because the entry in column 5 is different for those two triplets and finally the last one should show lines 2, 3, 4 because on line 5 column 5 is the same as coumn 5 on line 4. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I've modified the script. Hopefully this is nearer to what you a looking for?

Comment: I am trying to re-write and include `lower()` and `strip()` functionality on this line: `script: triplets[tuple(row[1:4])].append((line, list(map(str.lower, row[4:6]))))` but I can't find out how. Can you help me with that. I am not completely understand this line as well. I understand what it does, but I can't really transform it to for loop to strip the white spaces before and after.

Comment: You could add `row = list(map(str.strip, row))` on the line before.

Comment: you are a life savior :) Thanks a lot!